# Finite etale morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there nice sufficient condition for when a (flat, projective) morphism $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ to a smooth projective variety $Y$ with $|f^{-1}(y)| = m$ (distinct reduced points) for all $y \in Y$ is finite and etale?

What are some good examples to think about? A very simple one seems to be $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1 \setminus 0$ sending $z \mapsto z^2$. Most of the explicit examples I can come up with have to do with the case where $X$ and $Y$ are curves, but it would be nice to see what are some good higher dimensional examples.

Comment: In characteristic zero, this is always true and in positive characteristic, you will need separability.

Comment: It did seem plausible to me, but I wasn't sure about the details. Also, the conditions here seem a bit repetitive (e.g. flatness). Just to clarify, does this apply to a closed subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ for some $n$ with $f$ the restriction of the projection to $Y$ (this seems to just be the definition of a projective morphism)? Finally, are there any examples to be careful about in general where things look like they should be etale but aren't?

Comment: Flatness is automatic under your hypothesis, just finite (which with your fiber hypothesis is equivalent to proper).

Comment: Since flatness is redundant, is there a common situation for when $f$ is proper assuming that $|f^{-1}(y)| = m$ for all $y \in Y$? There was one example given in a previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643651/projections-are-finite-morphisms), but I'm not sure what is a good example to think about.